# how do I append path to my existing url through URI builder

Tags: url, groovy, uri, uribuilder

```
def uri = new UriBuilder('http://someurl.com/api')
```

I want to append `/$contacId/PhoneNumber` to the above `uri` .

How Do I handle this case

Comment: `def` is not part of Java syntax. Please add `tag` of language which you are using.

Comment: As mentioned in other comment, correct the language tag.

Comment: groovy is a subset of java!! everything is similar apart from the syntax  .The point here is about the URI builder class which is common in both .

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html  this is the api doc which is in Java. Anyhow thanks I fixed it .

Comment: You linked to `UriBuilder` but your code is using `URIBuilder`. Java is case sensitive, is groovy not? If it is case sensitive then is it typo or did you mean some other class like http://javadox.com/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.6/groovyx/net/http/URIBuilder.html?

Comment: Typo* yup exactly UriBuilder of java  which has a path method .

Answer (score 4):

use path method

```
def uri = new URIBuilder('http://someurl.com/api');
 uri.path("/$contacId/PhoneNumber");
```

Answer (score 3):

**One-Liner using [UriBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html):**

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder

def contactId = 42

def uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://someurl.com/api").path("$contactId/PhoneNumber")

println uri
```

**Output:**

```text
http://someurl.com/api/42/PhoneNumber
```

**Test:**

Copy-paste the code into https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/

Answer (score -1):

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html

def uri = new URIBuilder('http://someurl.com/api')
String appendPath = "/contact/$contactId/PhoneNumber"
        uri.path += appendPath;
```